# How to prove $H\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{e^{\frac{C}{4\pi}-\frac{3}{32}}\cdot A^{\frac{9}{8}}}{\sqrt 2}$

Tags: special-functions, closed-form, gamma-function

How to prove:
$$
H\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{e^{\frac{C}{4\pi}-\frac{3}{32}}\cdot A^{\frac{9}{8}}}{\sqrt 2}
$$
Where $C$ is Catalan's number, $A$ is Glaisher-Kinkelin's constant and $H(x)$ is the hyperfactorial given by:
$$
H(n)=\prod_{k=1}^{n} k^k
$$
$$
H(x-1)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}x(x+1)}\cdot n^{xn+\frac{1}{2}x(x+1)}\cdot H(n)}{x^x\cdot (1+x)^{1+x}\cdots(n+x)^{n+x}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

We will use $(3)$ from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html).

$$H(z-1)G(z)=e^{(z-1)\ln\Gamma(z)},$$

where $G$ is the [Barnes G-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html) and $\Gamma$ is the [Gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html).

In our special case

$$H\left(\frac 14\right)=\frac{e^{\frac 14 \ln \Gamma\left(5/4\right)}}{G\left(\frac 54\right)}.$$

The easy part of the problem is to see that

$$e^{\frac 14 \ln \Gamma\left(5/4\right)}=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \Gamma\left(\frac 14\right)^{1/4}.$$

From J. Choi and H. M. Srivastava *[Certain Classes of Series Involving the Zeta Function](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X98962163)* from page $92$ to $94$ we could derive that

$$G\left(\frac 54\right) = e^{3/32\,-\,G/(4\pi)}\,A^{-9/8}\,\Gamma\left(\frac 14\right)^{1/4},$$

here $G$ denotes [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant), and $A$ is the [Glaisher–Kinkelin constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant).

From here it comes that

$$H\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{e^{\frac{G}{4\pi}-\frac{3}{32}}\cdot A^{\frac{9}{8}}}{\sqrt 2}.$$